# Transmission stops responding frequently / slowing down Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, freeze, transmission

So I'm using Transmission to download some files but it has been acting really weird recently.

On the program, I'm getting a bit of slow download speed and the program freezes a lot, and sometimes the GUI stays black and white, even the close button, that usually is orange.

I'm also feeling that it is slowing down my pc in general. Folder browsing takes more time to load with the program on, and any music playing starts freezing (They work fine with the program off).

I've tried running Transmission on the terminal but I didn't got any error messages, and the freezing continued even after I closed Transmission, and I had to close the terminal for it to work (the process was still running, though).

I'm not sure what have caused this. Recently I've put Transmission to start with Ubuntu, and I have tried downloading a big file (like ~40 GB), but because of the constant freezing I gave up.

Comment: I've been having the same problem recently, for me I believe it is the OS Type, OS Type: x64; the laptop I'm using also is not the computer I used to install Ubuntu on this hard drive (I switched HDD's from my desktop to my laptop so i can use the internet and get updates) and I do not believe that this laptop is designed to run "x64" type systems. My main point is, make sure you have the proper OS type installed for that computers' motherboard (try looking up your motherboards' model or processor on the web to find spec. details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually in my `fstab` file, as can be seen in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399775/constant-freezes-when-downloading-torrent-to-ntfs-partition/399794?noredirect=1#399794).

Answer (score 1):

Try to lower the amount of maximum connected peers and try again.

[image]

Otherwise maybe it is a bug. This needs further discussion with the developers and I will suggest to open a bug report. See here [how to report bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The peer limits were already low (60 and 240, I think), but lowering them didn't worked. I think the problem isn't with Transmission, since now I am experiencing the same lag on rTorrent.

Comment: Try to open a port(port forwarding) in your router manually. I cannot give you general info, because of the differences on various router's configurations pages. Then assign this specific port in Transmission and check it. Also a phone-call  in you ISP wouldn't be bad. For port forwarding read the [manual of bittorent](http://www.bittorrent.com/help/manual/chapter0203)

Comment: Turns out the problem wasn't on Transmission, it was on my fstab file. It was making the NTFS partition (where I was saving the files) buggy and slow. Thank you so much for the help, though!

Comment: Wow, I couldn't think something like this. Please add your own answer and mark it as the correct one. It would be helpful for future reference.