# Constant freezes when downloading torrent to NTFS partition

Tags: freeze, ntfs, bittorrent

I'm trying to download some large files and save them on an NTFS partition, but I'm experiencing heavy freezes. This does not happen when I, say, set the torrent location to `/home/user/Downloads`, but I don't have enough free space on `~/`to download files there.

Is there any way to get rid of those freezes? I've tried Transmission and rTorrent, both had the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torrent's temporary files are still on your `/` partition (maybe `/tmp`, not sure). Check the options in your torrent client to change that temporary directory.

If that doesn't work, maybe you have a bug with your NTFS driver and you could try to reinstall `ntfs-3g` package:

1. Unmount your NTFS partition.
2. Use this command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall ntfs-3g
   ```

You can also check your `/etc/fstab` to see if your NTFS partition is correctly mounted (or use the GNOME GUI program `gnome-disks`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem was, indeed, on the `fstab` file. I forgot that I edited it to make the partition mount on Ubuntu startup. Must have screwed up something on the file. I'm using the backup that I made and the file is downloading with no problems.